# reactjs reflux handle login

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reactjs, rails-api, refluxjs

I'm new to ReactJS and I followed this tutorial: http://adamalbrecht.com/2015/07/20/authentication-using-json-web-tokens-using-rails-and-react/

After I make some corrections to the code to get it working on my setup, I can successfully login. But when I reload the page the SessionStore is empty.

My router:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux'
import { Router, Route, IndexRoute, hashHistory } from 'react-router';

// Base-Layout
import Base from './layout/base';

// Pages
import index from './pages/index';
import Login from './pages/Login';

import SessionStore from './stores/session_store.js';

function requireAuth(store) {
  return (nextState, replace) => {
    // let { auth } = store.getState();

    console.log(store.isLoggedIn());

    // if (!auth || !auth.loggedIn)
    //   replace({ pathname: loginPath, query: { return_to: nextState.location.pathname } });
  };
}

export default (
  <Provider store={SessionStore}>
    <Router history={hashHistory}>
      <Route path="login" name="Login" component={Login} />
      <Route path="/" name="Home" component={Base} onEnter={requireAuth(SessionStore)}>
        <IndexRoute component={index}/>
      </Route>
    </Router>
  </Provider>
);
```

When I go to index page after successfull login I get a "true" but when I reload the page I got an "false" maybe anyone can help me.

Comment: Are you using `reflux`, or `redux`? You say `reflux`, but then you've got `react-redux` in there, and are putting the store in a `react-redux` Provider, like it's a `redux` store.

Comment: I use reflux but I've read that I can use the store from reflux with redux. But that doesn't make my login persistent after page refresh. I think I should use localStorage.

Comment: Redux and Reflux stores are not interchangeable at all.

Not to mention: Reflux's methods of getting state into stores are far easier than Redux's. So not sure why you'd want to.

Comment: *out of stores, I mean.

Answer (score 1):

You should use [`localStorage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) instead of [`sessionStorage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage). This is because `sessionStorage` is cleared every time page session ends, e.g. page is refreshed.

Comment: When I'm logged in my sessionstoreage is empty. Why are you sure that the guy I'd using Sessionstoreage?

Comment: *is I can't see in the code what storage the guy is using.

Comment: @Evolutio I assume `SessionStore` is either browser's `sessionStorage` or a plain javascript object. Either way, these are not persisting through page refresh. Therefore, you need to store it either to `localStorage` or to the database.